# Java Screen Capture OpenGL and DirectX fullscreen Applications

Tags: java, opengl, directx, screenshot, fullscreen

I am trying to design a program in java to periodically (every 100 milliseconds or so) take screenshots of my display and compute the average pixel rgb values of the entire screen. I need this to be able to work with video games and iTunes/Quicktime videos. However I have tried using JNA and robot to capture the screen and it only works when I am not capturing a video game in full screen or an iTunes video. For instance I tested my code by saving an image to examine and see what is happening. When I am in a video game I only see a screenshot of a blank window. I think this is because games use directx or openGL and communicate with the hardware differently than your typical app.

If I use this [this](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Taking_Screen_Shots) method for capturing a screenshot instead of robot or JNA will this solve my problem? It looks like it is copying over data from the openGL screen buffer. What about DirectX applications?

I basically just want to be able to get the perceived pixel data on the screen at all times. Regardless of whether or not its a fullscreen DirectX or OpenGL application or not. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The lwjgl method will only screen shot the lwjgl display. ie if you created an app using lwjgl and wanted to screenshot its contents then it will work, but it won't capture the entire screen like you want

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess this is for a homebrew version of the amBX lighting system.  Even if it's not, the following page may help you; it contains both the java code and arduino code for a DIY ambient lighting setup, which needs to accomplish the same thing:

http://siliconrepublic.blogspot.com/2011/02/arduino-based-pc-ambient-lighting.html

Things to consider:
1.  For processing speed reasons, that sample of code purposely ignores some of the pixels on the screen
2.  Depending on what you're displaying (racing games vs. first-person shooters vs. top-down-view strategy or MOBA games vs. movies) you may want to purposely segment the display into separate sectors.  For example, for a racing game you may want both the left and right sides to be more independent and very responsive to rapid changes, whereas for general film viewing you may want a more general output because you're dealing with a wider variety of ways the camera can move.

Comment: Yes I am using this for an ambient lighting system! Good guess! Although this guy is doing it exactly the same way I am already doing it. He is using the robot class to create screenshots. When I do this it works but it doesn't work for fullscreen applications like video games or running an iTunes video in fullscreen. The only difference between his code and mine is that he is using Processing instead of Eclipse. I will try using the robot class in Processing to see if that solves my problem.

Comment: You may also want to try downloading VLC, diving into the advanced options, and seeing when it is/isn't capable of capturing pixel colors.  I'm not necessarily expecting it to work better or be a preferable program to view movies in, but by checking each of the many different output methods (DirectX being one of them) you may be able to glean some info that'll help in further searches & troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried VLC already and it does work. Do you happen to know what output method VLC uses?

Comment: Tools>Preferences>"All" radiobutton in the bottom left>scroll down left sidebar to "Video">Output Modules.  More choices and tweaks than you can shake an LED stick at.